# Azure ReservedIP endpoints

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-configuration, azure-deployment

I'm trying to provision a new Azure VM from an image via PowerShell and I need to use ReservedIP (which is why I'm using PowerShell - ReservedIP functionality isn't available from the management portal).

I'm running the following command:

```
New-AzureVMConfig -Name "myName" -InstanceSize Small -ImageName "imageName" | New-AzureVM -ServiceName "serviceName" -ReservedIPName "IP Name" -AffinityGroup "myAffinityGroup"
```

But I get the following error:

```
New-AzureVM : BadRequest: Deployment serviceName uses ReservedIP IP Name but does not contain any endpoints. Deployment must contain at least one endpoint in order to use a ReservedIP.
```

I can see that the cloud instance gets created, but it doesn't have any VM instance in it. Other Stack Overflow posts seem to imply that the above pshell commands should just work. None of the documentation addresses the need to add an endpoint and the VM doesn't even get created, so I don't know where I'd be able to add one.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

You need to add an `Add-AzureEndpoint` call after `New-AzureVMConfig` instead of after `New-AzureVM`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to move a machine to a cloud service with a static ip, so I deleted the VM (keeping the disk), then once the disk showed up for use I ran the code below.  I know it will have a bogus endpoint that I will have to remove and re-create later. I just wanted it to be created.

New-AzureVMConfig -Name "test" -InstanceSize Large -DiskName "test-test-0-201409031948580187" |Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "test" -Protocol "tcp" -PublicPort 80 -LocalPort 80 -LBSetName "test" -ProbePort 888 -ProbeProtocol "TCP"| New-AzureVM -ServiceName "test" –ReservedIPName "SQL-UAT-USEast" -VNetName "East-1" -Location "East US"